# Final Cut crashes when I press the "delete" key

Tags: crash, final-cut-pro

I am having a really difficult time while working on Final Cut Pro. When I am sorting footage and I press the "delete" key to reject a clip, FCP crashes. It doesn't happen every time but it happens very often. It breaks my flow of work. Can anybody please help me fix this? Thank You.